# Dockerfile ADD files fails

Tags: docker, newrelic

I'm stuck on this. I'm building a docker image via the this dockerfile

```
#
# Nginx Custom Domain Https Dockerfile
#
# Builds an OpenResty nginx image with auto-ssl capabilities
# See: https://github.com/GUI/lua-resty-auto-ssl
#

FROM openresty/openresty:latest-xenial

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN echo "license_key: 64553f3xxxxxxxxx" | tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra.yml


RUN curl https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/gpg/newrelic-infra.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN printf "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt xenial main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/newrelic-infra.list
RUN cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/newrelic-infra.list
RUN echo "license_key: 64553fxxxxxxxxxxxx" | tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra.yml
RUN cat /etc/newrelic-infra.yml
RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq newrelic-infra
```

....
   # there is more but see the issue below

I run it with

```
docker build -t XXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/qwilr-codebuild-base:latest .
```

The output of it is:

```
  Sending build context to Docker daemon  41.47kB
    Step

 1/19 : FROM openresty/openresty:latest-xenial
    ....
Step 9/19 : RUN echo "license_key: 64553f38xxxxxxxx" | tee 
-a /etc/newrelic-infra.yml
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 77cd0ece8528
Step 10/19 : RUN cat /etc/newrelic-infra.yml
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2cb1a27b4d8b
Get:1 https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt xenial/main amd64 newrelic-infra amd64 1.2.15 [4679 kB]
Fetched 4679 kB in 14s (325 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package newrelic-infra.
(Reading database ... 15601 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../newrelic-infra_1.2.15_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking newrelic-infra (1.2.15) ...
Setting up newrelic-infra (1.2.15) ...
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package newrelic-infra (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 newrelic-infra
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The command '/bin/sh -c DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq newrelic-infra' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

The problem seems to be that adding the newrelic-infra.yml file just does not work. I've also tried COPY and ADD. Is there something I'm missing which would cause this file to not be there for the following apt-get install command.

I have also run with --no-cache and still get the same error. The key failure I believe is that newrelic-infra install expects the file `/etc/newrelic-infra.yml` to be there, as highlighted by the line `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`

Is there a reason why files copied to /etc/ are failing? Is it the base image I'm using?

Comment: Hmmm...maybe the problem is in fact trying to install newrelic infrastructure agent on docker image. Then how is one supposed to run nginx integration for newrelic on a docker container.

Comment: I hope your dockerfile/resulting image does not contain the acual license key? This will expose the key to the world.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it an open issue.
[dpkg error processing package newrelic-infra](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/dpkg-error-processing-package-newrelic-infra-configure/44632)

Also, the package is missing under
[linux/apt](http://%20http://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt)